# Arduino MQTT through the SoftSerial port

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266

I know, my question could be very simply, but I can't figure out this stuff already three days.

I need to send some request to MQTT server from my Arduino nano through the ESP8266 module. I've found the good library for this task - PubSubClient.h. Here is an example how to do it:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[]    = {  0xDE, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(172, 16, 0, 100);
IPAddress server(172, 16, 0, 2);

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // handle message arrived
}

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, ethClient);
```

But I don't use Ethernet shield. I use ESP8266 connected to digital ports and create SoftwareSerial port for transmitting data using wifi:

```
SoftwareSerial espSerial(8,7);
```

And I can't use SoftwareSerial port and PubSubClient both. 
When I try this way:
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, 0, espSerial);
I get the error:

```
no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(byte [4], int, int, SoftwareSerial&)'
```

I've been trying to find the solve on the all of internet but I didn't have a success. Please, help me with this problem. What am I supposed to do?
I apologize for my bad English

Comment: Are you running C/C++ or Lua on the 8266?  Lua might make [more sense here](http://www.foobarflies.io/a-simple-connected-object-with-nodemcu-and-mqtt/)...  In fact, how big is the program? Do you need to use the arduino at all? the nodemcu modules (less than $7 USD) have a lot of I/O pins, 1 analog in, pwm etc...

Answer (score 2):

pubsubclient does not support softwareSerial library.you may use WiFiEsp library to use ESP8266 on SoftwareSerial with PubSubClient library.

Answer (score 1):

While the PubSubClient library lists the hardware it supports on it's [website](http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/) the reference to ESP8266 means that the library actually runs on the ESP8266 not on an Arduino connected to a ESP8266 via serial.

As @zipzit mentioned you may be able to do away with the Arduino all together and just use the ESP8266, depending on which version you have it may have nearly as many pins as the Arduino.

Otherwise you could just send the topic and value to the ESP8266 over the serial link and then use Lua and the built in [MQTT library](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/mqtt/) in [NodeMCU](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware) firmware to send the MQTT message.